# Invoke java program at specific intervals

Tags: java, operating-system, scheduling, scheduled-tasks

I have a program which reads Inbox messages from email accounts, as the title says i would like to run the program after every 1.5hrs.

Is there any OS(Windows and Linux) level or JVM level solution which would help in performing the task.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) of `ScheduledExecutorService`:

```
 import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.*;
 class BeeperControl {
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
       Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    public void beepForAnHour() {
        final Runnable beeper = new Runnable() {
                public void run() { System.out.println("beep"); }
            };
        final ScheduledFuture<?> beeperHandle =
            scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, 10, 10, SECONDS);
        scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
                public void run() { beeperHandle.cancel(true); }
            }, 60 * 60, SECONDS);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

On Windows use the `at` command or "Scheduled Jobs", on Linux use a `cron` job.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313565
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 0):

Create a [cron job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Type `crontab -e`

and add an entry for your command.